# Focus input added dynamically to observableArray in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, focus

In KO 3.0.0.beta (and I am almost sure it'd be the same in 2.3) I am trying to add new row to a dynamically created table:

**HTML**

```
<div id="root">
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: events">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-type="name" data-bind="value: name, css: {hidden: !editing()}, hasFocus: true">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-type="method" data-bind="value: age, css: {hidden: !editing()}">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $root = $('#root');

$root.on('blur', 'table input', function(event) {
    var data = ko.dataFor(event.target), 
        context = ko.contextFor(event.target),
        $input = $(event.target), 
        newData;

    data.editing(false);

    if($input.closest('td').is(':last-child') && $input.closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {
        newData = {
            name: '', 
            age: '', 
            editing: ko.observable(false)
        };

        context.$root.events.push(newData);
        newData.editing(true);  
    }
});

var data = {                
    events: [
        {name: 'aaa', age: '22', editing: false},
        {name: 'bbb', age: '33', editing: false},
        {name: 'ccc', age: '44', editing: false}
    ]
};

var mapping = {
    events: {
        key: function(data) {
            return ko.unwrap(data.name);
        }
    }
};

var observable = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);

ko.applyBindings(observable, $root[0]);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZenMaster/Tf8sH/)

and it **almost** works.

I am successful with row creation - which was the siple part, but for the life of me I can't make the first input in the created raw to be focused.

Any ideas (and I went through a ton of suggestions, none of which worked in the above setting)?

Comment: You´re mixing jQuery and KO, its doomed to fail. Add a observable isFocused, bind it against hasFocus binding

Comment: Second @Anders. You should turn that into an answer. It may not be what the OP's after, but it's the cleanest solution to the actual problem, and besides: others may find it helpful too.

Comment: @Anders jquery is for events binding. Totally orthogonal. I am open to suggestions so please DO make this an answer. And I tried with isFocused. Couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the point, but why not just set your hasFocus to editing() instead of true?

```
<div id="root">
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: events">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-type="name" data-bind="value: name, css: {hidden: !editing()}, hasFocus: editing()">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-type="method" data-bind="value: age, css: {hidden: !editing()}">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/BsBpu/)

Comment: Did you try your own fiddle? It doesn't work. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding... How is it supposed to work then?

Comment: The new row that is added should have the first input field focused - so that user can type right away, after pressing, say, "tab" on the previous row.

Answer (score 0):

It often pays of to avoid mixing jQuery with Knockout like that. For most cases Knockout also has options. In your case, the ones to look at are [the event binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) and [the hasFocus binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html).

Looking at your code, I'd update the View to something like this:

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: name, 
                                      hasFocus: editingName">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: age, 
                                      hasFocus: editingAge, 
                                      event: { blur: $root.onBlurAgeEdit }">
    </td>
</tr>
```

As an aside, if you're after "MS Word Style" creation of new rows when a user presses tab, you can also bind to the "keypress" event and check for the correct keycode (for tab).

Notice that I've split the `editing` observable in two observables: `editingName` and `editingAge`.

The function `onBlurAgeEdit` will fire whenever the age `input` blurs. It looks like this:

```
self.onBlurAgeEdit = function (item) {
    // Unwrap the array
    var myEvents = self.events();

    // Check if this function was called for the *last* item in the array
    if (myEvents[myEvents.length-1] === item) {

        // Make sure the last item isn't in edit mode anymore
        item.editingAge(false);

        // Push a new item that has *name* in edit mode
        self.events.push({name: ko.observable(''),
                          age: ko.observable(''),
                          editingName: ko.observable(true),
                          editingAge: ko.observable(false)});
    }
};
```

Note that for [Firefox you'll need to throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14482199/419956) the observables to make the `hasFocus` binding play nice.

See all this at work in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDCa4/2/).

Comment: I must be explaining it really bad. Yours does **exactly** what my original does. And it's not good. After pressing tab on the last visible input - a new row should be added and the first input in that row should be **focused** and ready to type. Also, you can see that I used `hasFocus` in the code above.

Comment: The correct behavior *does* occur in IE10 for me. To my surprise Webkit didn't work [until I let bits of the onBlur function run on its own thread](http://jsfiddle.net/hDCa4/2/). I didn't have time to get it to work on Firefox though, a straight up throttle extend didn't seem to work. For more info you may need to follow mentioned link and investigate some more.